# Under what conditions does $z^w$ have only one value?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In general, $z^w$ for $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$ has infinitely many values. This is because $z^w:= e^{w\log(z)}$, but $\log(z)$ is a multi-valued function. However, for certain values of $z$ and $w$, it is possible for $z^w$ to take only one value. Under what conditions does this occur?

Comment: It's true if $w\in\Bbb Z$; I suspect that's the only possibility.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So does that mean $1^z$ can take infinitely many values, for instance?

Comment: Well what happens when you work out $1^z$ from the definition?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Let's see. $1^z$ should be equal to $e^{z\log(1)}$. There are infinitely many logarithms of $1$, the most obvious being $0$. But if $z$ is a logarithm of $w$, then so is $z+(2\pi i) n$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, the logarithms of $1$ are $2\pi in$. Hence,
$$
1^z=e^{z\log(1)}=e^{z(2\pi i n)} \, .
$$
For $n=0$, we get $1^z=1$. For $n=1$, we get $1^z=e^{(2\pi i)z}$. If we let $z=x+iy$, the this simplifies to
$$
e^{(2\pi i)(x+iy)}=e^{2\pi i x} \cdot e^{-2\pi y} = e^{-2\pi y}\left(\cos(2 \pi x)+i\sin(2\pi x)\right) \, .
$$

Comment: This is an ugly expression, but the imaginary part could be non-zero, so presumably $1^z$ could take infinitely many values.